# Perl How to insert datetime in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, perl

I'm new to MongoDB, I have MySQL format dates in an array like `2018-08-13 09:56:19` and I wanted to store in MongoDB an ISODate with time_zone `-0500` so that date will be inserted like `"Date" : ISODate("2018-08-13T09:56:19.000-05:00")` through `Perl`

Any help Appreciated ...

Comment: You seem to have two unrelated questions? Please post them as separate Questions.

Comment: I use Cpanel::JSON::XS. Its `encode_json` is short for `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode`. It produces JSON encoded using UTF-8. It doesn't provide a function named `to_json`, which typically produces JSON that hasn't been encoded. You can use `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->encode` for that.

Comment: What problem are you having with `convert_blessed`?

Comment: @ikegami Those question is just for knowledge purpose. My main problem is that how I insert custom dates (from MySQL format) into MongoDB ISODate.

Comment: I don't know anything about MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a [DateTime](https://p3rl.org/DateTime) parser that speaks MySQL's format, but then MongoDB will convert DateTime objects correctly.  However, for efficiency, when querying it doesn't automatically inflate back to a DateTime object, but uses an intermediate form, [BSON::Time](https://p3rl.org/BSON::Time). There's a method, `as_datetime`, to get a DateTime object.

See the example below:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339;
use MongoDB;

# parse the date
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime( '2003-01-16 23:12:01' );
$dt->set_formatter("DateTime::Format::RFC3339");
say $dt;
# 2003-01-16T23:12:01+00:00

# set TZ
$dt->set_time_zone("America/New_York");
say $dt;
# 2003-01-16T23:12:01-05:00

# connect to the DB and get a MongoDB::Collection to work with
my $mc = MongoDB->connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
my $coll = $mc->ns('test.foo');

# insert
$coll->insert_one({ date => $dt });

# query
my $doc = $coll->find_one({date => $dt});

# dump the doc -- note the date is now a BSON::Time and there's a
# MongoDB '_id' field added
say Dumper $doc;
# $VAR1 = {
#           '_id' => bless( {
#                             'oid' => '[vöZN@®G¿Ç'
#                           }, 'BSON::OID' ),
#           'date' => bless( {
#                              'value' => '1042776721000'
#                            }, 'BSON::Time' )
#         };

# get it back as a DateTime object and print it out
my $date = $doc->{date}->as_datetime;
$date->set_formatter("DateTime::Format::RFC3339");
say $date;
# 2003-01-17T04:12:01Z
$date->set_time_zone("America/New_York");
say $date;
# 2003-01-16T23:12:01-05:00
```

Comment: For the timezone bit, you'll need to learn to work with DateTime objects, both when parsing and after you've round-tripped it, because MongoDB datetimes only use UTC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The date is storing in MongoDB as ISODate but it by default adding different timezone. how I force it to store the date with -0500 timezones.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  You can call `$dt->set_date_time("America/New_York")` in the example above after parsing to attach a time zone to the parsed datetime.  Then when you insert into MongoDB, it will be stored "correctly" (as milliseconds since unix epoch).  When you pull it back out as `$date`, you can again call `$date->set_time_zone("America/New_York")` to attach a time zone to it.  I'll edit my code above to do that and print it out so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Also, if you find I've answered your question, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: I've revised the code again to use a different formatter that more clearly shows the timezone data.